# Connection timed out: Connect

Tags: force.com-ide

While developing against sandbox (CS21) I continue to get time outs from Force IDE (Eclipse) when refreshing or saving changes to salesforce. This happens in a number of situations including

- refreshing to select metadata resources for inclusion in package
- saving to sandbox
- deploying to production
- refreshing current data from sandbox

I have not pulled out wireshark yet and watched the packets go by yet but would anyone have any guidance on why I'm getting this error? Its really putting a crimp in productivity.

Update 1: This issue has been happening using the last 2 recent versions of the Force IDE the previous being winter 14 and current summer 15. Overall it seems to be network related but where in the network I have not determined, local, isp or on the salesforce side.

Comment: n.b. we have noted timeout issues on Summer 15 sandboxes (cs11) - apex tests failing with timeouts - not repeatable - worked fine on v33